# How do i concat csv files to end up with the one csv file with stacked data using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, merge, concatenation

I want to concat csv files on top of each other vertically/stacked and save that to a new csv. The testing.csv file should just have the 2 csv files data stacked. The images below show the original csv files for both msft and adbe, but once concat is used, it comes out with one horizontal line of data. How to do this?

```
import pandas as pd
    
data_msft = pd.read_csv("MSFT.csv",header = 0, index_col= None)
data_adbe = pd.read_csv('ADBE.csv',header = 0, index_col= None)

data = pd.concat([data_msft,data_adbe],ignore_index=True,axis=0,sort=False)

data.to_csv("testing.csv")

enter code here
```

[image]

above is MSFT.csv

[image]

above is ADBE.csv

[image]

above is how the csv concats

[image]

above is what i am trying to achieve after csv files are concat.

this is the plain txt of data.

MSFT  211001P00295000,299.09,295.0,5.37,0.0,20211001,0.0,29/08/2021 16:10:00,29/08/2021 16:11:40

ADBE  211001P00650000,652.39,650.0,21.22,0.0,20211001,0.0,29/08/2021 16:10:00,29/08/2021 16:11:15

Below is how the data returns after concat of the above csv files

,MSFT  211001P00295000,299.09,295.0,5.37,0.0,20211001,0.0.1,29/08/2021 16:10:00,29/08/2021 16:11:40,ADBE  211001P00650000,652.39,650.0,21.22,29/08/2021 16:11:15

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

csv_files = ['path/to/file1.csv', 'path/to/file2.csv']
concat_csvs = []

for filename in csv_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    concat_csvs.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(concat_csvs, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
frame.to_csv()
```